# ASP.NET TextBox OnTextChanged event not fire

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I've the following problem: asp.net TextBox server side control, fire onTextChanged only when it loose focus. 
I would like to fire my server side event  each time user press a key. 
How can i do ? 
Thanks

Comment: Sure you want to do that?? Could be too expensive from resources point of view. Maybe we can give you a different approach if you give us more details about the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" onkeyPress="MyKeyPressEvent;" ID="txtUserName" />
```

Just add the onkeyPress client event to your textbox.

Then in your JavaScript function "MyKeyPressEvent", call a PageMethod that fires your event method.

Pagemethods are good with onkeyPress, since they have very small Request sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Going to have to use ajax since the keypress is a client side event.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript and pagemethods to make it as efficient as possible

use the onkeyup to call a function where you call your pagemethod

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article454-using-pagemethods-and-json-in-aspnet-ajax.aspx - pagemethods