# ASP.NET TextBox OnTextChanged Event not fired

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, search, textbox

I'm trying to add a search functionality where the website sends a request to the server to gather information each time the user enters text (letter by letter). For this I'm in need of OnTextChanged event I assume? I tried using it but the event won't fire.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="futu_search" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search" OnTextChanged="futu_search_TextChanged"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And my code behind:

```
protected void futu_search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //I kept a break point here to see if it's fired
       //Send requests
}
```

What do you think is wrong? Do yall have a better solution than the 'OnTextChanged event' to get each key press and for a search box?

Comment: I think the *OnTextChanged* event fires when you loose focus and not while you type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its better to use **ajax** and **jquery** for what you are trying to accomplish than to **postback** every key press.

Please check [**this LINK**](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for more details and example.

Also, the *OnTextChanged* event fires when you loose focus and not while you type, which seems your requirement.

From an answer in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/436223/Asp-Net-textbox-TextChanged-event-is-not-firing):

> TextChanged: "Occurs when the content of the text box changes between
>   posts to the server." AutoPostBack: "Use the AutoPostBack property to
>   specify whether an automatic postback to the server will occur when
>   the TextBox control loses focus. Pressing the ENTER or the TAB key
>   while in the TextBox control is the most common way to change focus."

*Sample code* :

*Source* : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",          
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT** : If you still plan to use keypress then read below quote,

> The value of the input text box, during onKeyPress is always the value
>   before the change.

Also it wont fire for "backspace" in chrome. 
[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/9/)

If you are still interested in OnKeyPress, I suggest you to have a look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365686/how-to-get-text-of-an-input-text-box-during-onkeypress).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885423/asp-net-textbox-ontextchanged-event-not-fire?rq=1) is what you are trying to do, but the question is old and newer and better things have come up like HTML 5.

**Note** : Using on KeyUp Event would not trigger if you use *Right click => Paste*. To check here is a Fiddler [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pazcw136/2).

Comment: I will try this too. Also Is there a OnKeyPress event?

Comment: There is an OnKeyPress but I'm afraid that is not exactly what you might be looking for

Answer (score 3):

Enable autopostback true ..

```
<asp:TextBox AutoPostback="true" ID="futu_search" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search" OnTextChanged="futu_search_TextChanged"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you want to fire the event when user press key than you have to use java script **onkeyup ** event

```
<asp:TextBox onkeyup ="return abc(event)" AutoPostback="true" ID="futu_search" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search" OnTextChanged="futu_search_TextChanged"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


<script>
function abc(evt) {

         ..put here your logic
        }
</script>
```

Comment: How do you use **keypress** to get the text to be used for searching?

Comment: Ohh Sorry its my mistake onkeyup  event is correct one .I updated My answer Please Check....Thanx for Find Bug @Rohit

Comment: still you just have the last pressed key. No the input filed's text.

Comment: That you can Simply get by $("#textboxid").val() ..@Rohit

Comment: Yeah, you must store up the previous value in some global variable to ensure the text has changed, and if yes then do a server fetch. Doesn't that seem a lot complicated?

Comment: Here is a fiddler for what you are trying to do => https://jsfiddle.net/pazcw136/2/

Comment: That's alternative approach...I suggest my opinion You have to Find Which is most useful to you..@Rohit

Comment: Try right click on the text box and paste. The KeyUp wouldn't fire unless you press a key on the keyboard in the input area.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `OnTextChanged` event will not trigger as its `AutoPostBack` property is false by default. So to make it happen please set its value to true.

And `OnTextChanged` event will only trigger when the textbox focus lost. So in this case you can use **AJAX** to get the value.

For that, you can use `onkeyup` to get the value in a javascript function at every characted enter.

Comment: Is there a OnKeyPress event?

Comment: No. But onkeypress event is there which is a javascript event. 
keypress happens before the change, keyup happens after.
So in his case you can use onkeyup to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to set the focus:

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
sm.SetFocus(myTextBox);
```

To set focus and select text of a you have to use the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "selectAndFocus", "$get('" + myTextBox.ClientID + "').focus();$get('" + myTextBox.ClientID + "').select();", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Include Autopost back tag in the control tag.  **AutoPostback="true"**

```
<asp:TextBox AutoPostback="true" ID="txtcontrol"  OnTextChanged="txtcontrol_TextChanged"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: The OnTextChanged event fires when you loose focus and not while you type.